# sharing $scope between 2 function within one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$stateParams','getTopicContent', function($scope,$http,$stateParams,getTopicContent){

    $scope.ionLoader = true;

    getTopicContent.request($stateParams.topicId).then(function(response){
        $scope.threadContent = response.data;

    }).finally(function(){
        $scope.ionLoader = false;
    });


    $scope.loadPages = function ($scope) {
        if(totalPages > 1){
                $http({
                url: "http://someurl.php",
                method: "GET",
                params: {topicId: $stateParams.topicId,page : 2}
            }).success(function(data){
                 $scope.threadContent.push(data);
            });
        }
    }


}]);
```

I got an error saying push of undefined. loadPages only fire when the user scrolled to the bottom of the page so I don't think it's an async issue, probably $scope problem? getTopicContent is my service.

Comment: Why did you add $scope parameter in loadPages function? You can override $scope that doing.

Comment: @xio4 is not the cause of the problem?

Comment: Your `getTopicContent.request()` returns a `promise` right? I tough it's an async issue, or try to define `$scope.threadContent = []` or `null` in your $scope first. And make sure your `$scope.threadContent` is exist before pushing something to it.

Comment: @AndiNugrohoDirgantara I tried that, the error gone but now I'm facing another issue. The data become empty after pushed.

Comment: What are you trying? `$scope.threadContent = []` or `$scope.threadContent = null`? Empty in here means `[]`, `null`, or `undefined`? If it's `[]` I thought it's your async issue that you must resolve in your `getTopicContent` service.

Comment: I don't have issue with async problem since I use a promise. But the ng-repeat of my data is blank after pushed. loadPages is a function for infinity scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promise for async working and remove parameter $scope in loadPages like that:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$stateParams','getTopicContent', function($scope,$http,$stateParams,getTopicContent){

    $scope.ionLoader = true;

    var promise = getTopicContent.request($stateParams.topicId).then(function(response){
        $scope.threadContent = response.data;

    }).finally(function(){
        $scope.ionLoader = false;
    });


    $scope.loadPages = function() {
        if(totalPages > 1){
                $http({
                url: "http://someurl.php",
                method: "GET",
                params: {topicId: $stateParams.topicId,page : 2}
            }).success(function(data){
                 promise.then(function(none) { 
                    $scope.threadContent.push(data); 
                 });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```